# Could not find .jar file Searched in the following locations: https://jcenter.bintray.com/

Tags: android, libraries, jcenter

I'm trying to upload my library to Jcenter
When I tested my lib I got this error
Could not find .jar file Searched in the following locations:https://jcenter.bintray.com/
And I didn't find .arr file in my repo .. 
Help please :)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpmSx.png)

Comment: please, attach gradle code how you add this dependency

Comment: Try changing **https** to **http** (the prefaces jcenter)

Comment: compile 'com.abanoub.androidlib:walkthrough:1.0.0'

and this what uploaded to Jcenter
http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/abanoub/androidlib/walkthrough/1.0.0/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script publishes both `debug` and `release` artifacts. but you add dependency without specifying any of them. Also, you need to specify the `aar` type:

```
compile 'com.abanoub.androidlib:walkthrough:1.0.0:release@aar'
```

Comment: Gradle BUILD SUCCESSFUL ..
but when I'm trying to use my lib classes it doesn't exist ..

Comment: I downloaded your artifacts and there are no classes in it, except `BuildConfig`. Something wrong with the assembling. Attach your `build.gradle` plz

Comment: apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    publishNonDefault true

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'

Comment: @AbanoubSamaan, it's getting harder. plz create new question `why your artifact has no classes`. attach the `build.gradle` that assembles and publisher the articafact.

Comment: Hi @AbanoubSamaan, How you solved it.. Am facing the same with my lib.. need your help.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was caused by a caching issue. Found out that on another computer, it was working as expected. 
Re-creating the project fixed the problem.